# React Native iOS to production issues

Tags: ios, react-native

im getting into RN and i want to install my app into my device (production) to take it to anywhere... but i dont know why i cant finish the process, some errors show up.

I'm reading step by step the guide from here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Using the release method from the guide, i got this error:

> main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native

And i tried the CLI too (react-native run-ios --configuration Release) and the command is looking for index.js

> "Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots"

The thing is, I tried some weeks ago with a version of RN where I can have an index.ios.js and index.android.js, and now, i'm using RN 0.50.3 and I just have an App.js, there is not more index.ios.js/index.android.js, and that is ok the documentaion is talking about just one file called App.js...
but why is the RN 0.50.3 searching for a index.js?

Why the index.js is missing in my project?, how i can fix this things?

I'm using:

```
MAC 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1 
react-native: 0.50.3
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you list app dirs how does it look like

Comment: @Ahmedfaragmostafa here https://ibb.co/f7jopm